# PNP set created by Value for a Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, pnp-powershell

When i am trying to do a bulk import of files using PNP i am unable to retain the created by Value (The files are in a local file share) .I am able to set all the other values (Created,Editor,Modified) but not Author.These are the various approaches i have tried so far .Can you please provide any suggestion

```
Add-PnPFile -Path "C:\temp\test.txt" -Folder "Shared Documents"  -Values @{Created="7/24/2019";Author="test@test.com";Editor="test@test.com";Modified="02/23/2012"}
Add-PnPFile -Path "C:\temp\test.txt" -Folder "Shared Documents"  -Values @{Created="7/24/2019";Author=14}
Set-PnPListItem -List "Shared Documents" -Identity 11 -Values @{"Title" = "Test Title"; Author="test@test.com"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the Author and Editor's userId in the double-quotes.

For example, `Author="14";Editor="15"`

Here is the complete working code.

```
Add-PnPFile -Path "C:\temp\test.txt" -Folder "Shared Documents"  -Values @{Created="7/24/2019";Author="14";Editor="15"}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot :)